# Access 2013 database on a read-only share

Tags: microsoft-access

We have a database on a Read Only share. Access 2013 will not open the file as it cannot create the lock file. Access 2010 never had this problem

What settings can I change to get the database to open?

The database is in use by multiple people, so currently there is a mix of 2010 and 2013 users, so app deployment is not an option currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution was to add a system/hidden folder with the same name as the database.

e.g. Database is `XXX.accdb`
Folder to be created is `XXX.laccdb`